# sql query to populate a class object that contains list of string

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

i am creating a project for survey, Survey has some multiple choice questions. For survey and question, I have a class,

```
@Entity
public class SurveyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private String surveyId;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private List<QuestionEntity> questions; 
}


@Entity
public class QuestionEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private String questionId;
    private String description;
    private String correctAns;
    private List<String> options;
}
```

and i want to pre-populate data into it at the startup of project. So i wrote a sql file (`initial.sql`) and put it into the `application.properties` of Spring Boot,

```
insert into SurveyEntity(surveyId, title, description) values("Survey1", "Collected Survey", "description of the survey1");

insert into QuestionEntity(questionId, description, correctAns, ?) values ("Question1", "Largest Country in the World", "Russia", ??);
insert into QuestionEntity(questionId, description, correctAns, ?) values ("Question2", "Most populous Country in the World", "China", ??);
insert into QuestionEntity(questionId, description, correctAns, ?) values ("Question3", "Highest GDP in the World", "United States", ??);
insert into QuestionEntity(questionId, description, correctAns, ?) values ("Question4", "Second largest English speaking country", "India", ??);
```

My question is, how can i populate list of String (`options` filed) using above statement? or do i need to create a separate table for `options` ?

Comment: If you wrote an SQL file then you need to put SQL in there, relative to the TABLE(s) represented by that class. A `List<String>` will not be stored in a single column unless you defined an `AttributeConverter` for it, so where is it stored?

Comment: Actually i do not understand what you mean. But i try.
Neither I have a separate class for **options** nor AttributeConverter.
I intended to save the multiple choice into **options** only.

Comment: You said you wrote an SQL file. So that SQL file needs to include SQL statements. What is the STRUCTURE (DDL) of the table where this CLASS `QuestionEntity` is mapped to? Where is the FIELD `options` stored? In which TABLE / COLUMN?!

Comment: I got it. I edit my question.

Comment: @NeilStockton I am relatively new to SpringBoot so you might find some lack of knowledge as well. This is my first Spring boot project. I would be happy if you could point it out.

Comment: This is nothing to do with SpringBoot and everything to do with JPA. You need to DEFINE HOW you are MAPPING that field of that class. You can persist it into a separate TABLE, or into a single COLUMN. Read some JPA docs, http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/mapping.html#one_many_nonpc_join